# parallax scroll with position sticky not working together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There are 3 divs, 
1. Top bar
2. slider
3. navigation

I implemented parallax scroll on navigation with the [code](http://codepen.io/JTParrett/pen/BkDie) below.

```
<script>   
    $.fn.moveIt = function(){
        var $window = $(window);
        var instances = [];

        $(this).each(function(){
            instances.push(new moveItItem($(this)));
        });

        window.onscroll = function(){
            var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
            instances.forEach(function(inst){
                inst.update(scrollTop);
            });
        }
    }

    var moveItItem = function(el){
        this.el = $(el);
        this.speed = parseInt(this.el.attr('data-scroll-speed'));
    };

    moveItItem.prototype.update = function(scrollTop){
        var pos = scrollTop / this.speed;
        this.el.css('transform', 'translateY(' + -pos + 'px)');
    };

    $(function(){
        $('[data-scroll-speed]').moveIt();
    });
</script>
```

The script is working perfectly, but i want the bottom navigation when scrolled to the top sticks at 30pixels from top, so i implemented the css below.

```
nav{
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 30px;
}
```

both code dosent work together, it may be a position issue, I want to get both this working together, any suggestion please.